# \nameref only shows reference as a red rectangle, no name in it

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, revtex

I'm trying to use `\usepackage{hyperref}` to reference in the text a section by name. The section to be referenced is

```
\section{whatever}\label{sec:marker}
```

However, when I place in the text

```
\nameref{sec:marker}
```

I get nothing but a narrow red rectangle without a text in it (I expected the text 'whatever' to appear there). Is there anything else I should do to fix this problem?

Here is a MWE of the problem I have:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside]{revtex4}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{sansmath}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\pdfpagewidth 8.32in
%\pdfpageheight 11in
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-20mm}
%\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-2mm}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2mm}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{170mm}
%\usepackage{anttor}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{s}{,}{,}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{pgothic}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{eufrak}
%\usepackage{oldgerm}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{FirstSection}

In \nameref{sec:marker} it is stated that ...

\section*{SecondSection} \label{sec:marker}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: Did you compile the document at least twice?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem you describe having encountered, i.e., I get a nice little red rectangle with "whatever" inside it. Please provide a full, compilable MWE that generates the (unwanted) behavior.

Comment: @Werner, yes I did. After you mentioned it, I did it again. No cigar.

Comment: Now I see where might be the problem. I tried it with  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} and it does work.

Comment: The problem apparently is in revtex4

Comment: Thanks for posting a working example. As it's not exactly "minimal", I've taken the liberty of commenting out all statements in the preamble except the `\usepackage{hyperref}` instruction. That way, casual readers will pick up right away that the problem is due to some interaction between the `revtex` document class and the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [`revtex4`](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4) plays some tricks on [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). That is, `revtex4` redefines the sectional macros that `hyperref` is tapping into, leading to the "lost `\nameref`".

To fix this, you need the [`xpatch` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) and patch the correct sectional macros: `\@ssect@ltx` and `\@sect@ltx`, each of which are called depending on whether you use the starred variant (or not) of the sectional command.

Here's a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4}% http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@ssect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}% Patch \<section>*
\xpatchcmd{\@sect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}% Patch \<section>
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\section{FirstSection} \label{sec:marker1}
In \nameref{sec:marker2} it is stated that \ldots

\section*{SecondSection} \label{sec:marker2}
You can also see in \nameref{sec:marker1} that \ldots
\end{document}
```

`\nameref` relies on the macro `\@currentlabelname` that contains the title used in the sectional unit. This title is stored in argument `#8` with a call to either `\@ssect@ltx` or `\@sect@ltx`. So, the patch restores this definition at an appropriate place within the macros.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this patch works (and is needed!) for the `revtex4-1` document class as well.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble installing xpatch package. Should I open a new question to address this problem or I should continue discussing it here?

Comment: We can try and hash it out here. If not, it's best to post a [ollow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how). If you're using TeX Live, you should use, from the command line, `tlmgr install xpatch`, or better yet, `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`. If you're running MiKTeX, you need to use the MiKTeX Package Manager. This is better than installing the packages yourself. The package managers put stuff in the right location, and update the appropriate filename databases (FNDB).

Comment: I'm using MikTeX but no repository I've tried so far seems to carry xpatch. Do you know of any that would?

Comment: The repositories available in MiKTeX do not list the one you pointed to: http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch. How can I reach it through MikTeX?

Comment: According to [`xpatch` on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch), it is available as part of the MiKTeX distribution. However, download [`xpatch.ins`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch/xpatch.ins) and [`xpatch.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch/xpatch.dtx) and run `pdflatex xpatch.ins`. Do this in your working folder. It should create, as output, `xpatch.sty` that you need. Then try and recompile your original document.

Comment: I did that (download ins and dtx files and run pdflatex xpatch.ins) but it still doesn't work. In MiKTeX, xpatch shows up in the packages list but isn't installable. None of the various repositories seem to have installable xpatch either.

Comment: Then I suggest posting a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) if the manual way doesn't work either. Remember to include as much information as possible: What version of MiKTeX you're using; what is the error messages you're getting when you run `pdflatex xpatch.ins`, etc.