# How to install the xpatch package in MiKTeX?

Tags: installing, miktex, updating, xpatch

This is a follow up question to [\nameref only shows reference as a red rectangle, no name in it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44714/nameref-only-shows-reference-as-a-red-rectangle-no-name-in-it).

In the answers to the question cited @Werner suggested to have the package `xpatch` installed so that `revtex4` can properly do cross-referencing. Thus, after a number of attempts (because instead of a file to save I was getting a listing of code) I was able to download `xpatch.ins` and `xpatch.dtx`, placed them in the working folder and ran `pdflatex xpatch.ins` from within WinEdt. Then I tried to compile the TeX document (<kbd>F9</kbd>) and got the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle command.
```

Notice, I'm trying to compile @Werner's minimal working example given in the original question cited above.

Now that I was unsuccessful in this compilation, I reverted to MiKTeX, trying to install `xpatch` from there. I started the MiKTeX package manager and it was soon populated with a list of packages. The package `xpatch` was in the list but was uninstallable. So, I tried to get it from the list of repositories which show up when going to Repository->Change Package Repository. None of these repositories, however, seems to contain `xpatch`. Also, none of these repositories is the one @Werner pointed to in the original question; namely, http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch and I couldn't find a way to get to it through MiKTeX. So, the problem still stands -- how can I install `xpatch` so that `revtex4`'s cross-referencing starts working?

EDIT: I'd like to add that before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in WinEdt after the unsuccessful compilation, the error seen is

```
1.55 \documentclass[full]{
                          13doc}
?
! Emergency stop.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install `xpatch` via the *MiKTeX Package Manager*. In your windows program folder are the folders *Maintenance* and *Maintenance (Admin)*. For package installation you should start the *Package Manager* as admin. In the menu *Repository* just *Synchronize* yours with the source repository first. After that look for the `xpatch` package, mark it and click *Install* in the *Task* menu. Thats all. If there are other packages which are needed by `xpatch` and they aren't installed just repeat the procedure with the *Manager*. To install all non installed packages in one run, go to *Edit* --> *Select Installable Packages* and than *Task* --> *Install*. So you have all available packages on your computer.

If you have other problems with the package (or with others), start the *Update(Admin)* in the *Maintenance (Admin)* folder and refresh the complete MiKTeX first.
[image]

Comment: @Holle I would suggest first synchronising the Package Manager, and then doing updates both in Admin and standard mode first.

Comment: Joseph, how does MikTeX package manager allow you to do updates in Admin mode?

Comment: @Holle, Seems I'm following your instructions, the installations starts and seemingly completes but at the end an error message appears saying:

Comment: The operation failed for some reason.

Comment: I don't see folders Maintenance and Maintenance (Admin). Maybe I'm not starting mpm right and that's the problem.

Comment: Now I used a third computer and I was able to do the installation. I copied the xpatch.sty into the working directory but it still doesn't compile well and is giving me the sem error I reported above. Probably I should copy other files too?

Comment: When I start compiling more and more sty files come up that are needed, such as l3names.sty, b3bottstrap.sty, l3basics.sty etc. Then, when I find them on the net, even further problems pop up. Don't know what to do with.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Holle, I got it. I had to go to yet another computer which started installing the needed sty files one by one stating each time: 'The package will be installed from: <Random package repository>. Now everything works great. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to thank @Werner too, who gave the working 'minimal working example'.

Comment: @ganzewoort: [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) uses some of the LaTeX3 concepts and style files. That's why you actually required other style files to be updated as well (`l3names`, ...). It would be best if you just update your entire distribution some time, rather than only the packages that you think you might need.

Comment: I don't quite know what is meant by distribution. What I've done is, I have WinEdt which I've been using for quite a while and the basic MiKTeX. My main concern is grandfathering. You see what troubles I'm getting into at times. Call me paranoid but it seems there are always some little details that have to be ironed out every time something changes. This makes me reluctant to change installations. Well, I may be totally wrong about that but maybe that's my conservative nature speaking. Thanks for suggesting it, anyway.

Comment: A repository or distribution is the bundle of all latex packages which are provided by MiKTeX. I think you should do the following: 1. Log in as an admin. 2. Start the Update tool in the MiKTeX program folder. Maybe the core program of MiKTeX is updated first, than repeat the update again to refresh the latex packages. 3. Start the MiKTeX Package Manager and start Repository --> Synchronize. 4. Click Edit --> Select Installable Packages. 5. Click Task --> Install. After all you can repeat the update with the Update tool. Now you should have a complete MiKTeX with the latest latex packages.

Comment: I really got into trouble here. While that fourth computer did install automatically all the packages needed and all is well there, my original computer has MiKTeX 2.7 and it isn't supported any more with package updates. So, I had to try installing MiKTeX 2.8 which turned out to be a problem too. In addition, my WinEdt is set to work with MiKTeX 2.7 and there's no way to get it to work with MiKTeX 2.8. If I now decide to get the updated version of WinEdt, it won't work with my original computer since it doesn't have Windows XP Service Pack 3 installed (can't be installed).

Comment: I would disadvise you to use such an old version from MiKTex. I have no experience in using the portable version of MiKTeX, but maybe you give it a try http://miktex.org/portable/about . With this tool you can install the recent MiKTeX with the latest packages on an USB-stick. In WinEdt you have to change the paths to the MiKTeX folders (WinEdt-->Options-->Execution Modes-->TeX System).

Comment: Now, that's a very good advice. This is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you @Holle.